# Python @variable.setter causing recursive limit to be reached?

Tags: python

Method call that is getting the error is `tile.path = false`

```
def createMaze():
    def createTileMatrix():
        for x in range(size):
            for y  in range(size):
                tile = tiles.tiles()
                tile.path = False
                if(x == 0 or y == 0 or x == size - 1 or y == size -1):
                    tile.border = True
                else:
                    tile.border = True
                tile.wall = True
                tile.lit = False
                tile.string =  False
                tile.spawn = False
                tileMatrix[x][y] = tile
```

Below is the part of the tiles class that is causing the error

```
    path = None
    wall = None
    string = None
    topLeftXCoord = None
    topLeftYCoord = None
    spawn = None
    lit = None
    border = None
    sprite = None

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self.path

    @path.setter
    def path(self, c):
        if c == True or c == False:
                self.path = c
        else:
            raise Exception("cannot set path equal to a non boolean function")
```

Something is causing Python to reach the recursion limit. My debugger shows the code is looping between lines `if c == True or c == False:` and `self.path = c` I am unsure what is causing this error

Answer (score 0):

Since `path` is the name of the property, you need a separate variable to store the actual value; normally it would be named `_path` (with an underscore). Otherwise, your getter calls itself recursively and so does your setter; the line `self.path = c` inside the setter is what causes the recursive call to the setter, since the setter handles all assignments like `self.path = ...`.

Here's an example of how to do it correctly:

```py
class Example:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        if value >= 0:
            self._foo = value
        else:
            raise ValueError()
```

Note that `_foo` with an underscore only needs to be used in the getter and setter; other methods such as `__init__` can and should use `foo` (without the underscore) to invoke the getter or setter.